# Echo query before execution and without execution in codeigniter Active Record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am looking for a way to see generated string of the query but **without** executing it.

Note that the query hasn't been executed before. (I do not want `$this->db->last_query();`)

I hope there be a method with a name like `$this->db->echo_query_string($table_name = '');` to be used **exactly like** `$this->db->get($table_name = '');` **BUT THE ONLY DIFFERENCE BE THAT** `get()` executes the code, but `echo_query_string()` just echoes the string of query **without execution**.

Comment: A simple - but probably not so effective - way I would do is slightly modify the query to make an erroneous query such that the system displays the error along with the simple expected error & it will not be executed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can see the compiled query by either of these functions

```
/* SELECT */ $this->db->_compile_select();
/* INSERT */ $this->db->_insert();
/* UPDATE */ $this->db->_update();
```

Comment: Thank you. Does that work just for select queries? Isn't there anything exactly instead of `get()`? I hope it be able it to have an optional $database_name like `get()`

Comment: For insert its $this->_insert() for update its  $this->_update() But these two require few arguments

Comment: Is there a document about describing the methods you mentioned? I want to know exactly the parameters they accept. I think it hardly has such a doc. Should I know more details by only looking at the code?

Comment: In the newest CodeIgniter version `$this->db->_compile_select()` is protected, and cannot be called.  You need to use `$this->db->get_compiled_select()` (which may or not be in the latest stable version, it's in their dev version).

Comment: You also need to use `get_compiled_insert` and `get_compiled_update` instead.

Comment: @Rocket Thank you very much. Do you mean version 2.0.3 that is currently the most stable version?

Comment: @smhnaji: I think `_compile_select` still works in 2.0.3, but that's not the most stable.  The most stable version is 2.1.0 which removes `_compile_select`.  They added `get_compiled_select`, but that's not in the stable version, it's only in the [development version](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter).

Answer (score 18):

You don't need to change any file in codeigniter because it already provides a method to do that.

Using

`echo $this->db->last_query();`

will produce

`select * from some_table...`

And this is it.

Comment: why -ve votes? Answer seemed perfect to me. Most probably down votes are not for discouragement so what's missing is comment.

Comment: -ve votes because the asker doesn't want to run the actual query. Just wants what the query will look like. last_query() gets the last query sent to the DB.

Comment: Down votes are because the question specifically said NO last_query(), and to top it all off - the "answer" starts with "tsc, tsc". Arrogant attitude, and wrong answer. Hard not to down vote, really.

Comment: `$this->db->last_query()` is good to see the query AFTER execution. OP wants to see the compiled query before and without executing it.

Comment: The op asked to show the SQL string without running the sql against the database. You can only use $this->db->last_query() after running get(), which will run the query against the database.

Comment: This post is the correct answer to the wrong question.  Upvoters are not considering the impact on future researchers.  Just because "it worked for you" doesn't mean that it is a correct answer to the posted question.

Answer (score 11):

I added this little method in DB_active_rec.php

```
function return_query()
{
    return $this->_compile_select();
}
```

Usage

```
$this->db->select('id,user_name')->from('user')->where('id',1);

$string =   $this->db->return_query();
echo $string;
```

Result

```
SELECT `id`, `user_name` FROM (`user`) WHERE `id` = 1
```

In this way you are bound to use

```
$this->db->from()
```

Instead of

```
$this->db->get()
```

Which runs the query

Answer (score 5):

You can use some **public methods** to get SQL queries

### Get a SELECT query

```
$sql = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
```

### Get a INSERT query

```
$sql = $this->db->get_compiled_insert();
```

### Get a UPDATE query

```
$sql = $this->db->get_compiled_update();
```

### Get a DELETE query

```
$sql = $this->db->get_compiled_delete();
```

Answer (score 4):

As of version 3 of Codeigniter, please refer to [this](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html) url and also to [this](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html).

- `echo $this->db->update_string();`   OR  `echo $this->db->get_compiled_update();`
- `echo $this->db->insert_string();`   OR   `$this->db->get_compiled_insert();`
- `echo $this->db->get_compiled_delete();`
- `echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();`

Answer (score 1):

From CI 3.1.11 The below code will help you

```
$this->db->get_compiled_select()
```

Form more details visit https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data