# Print query before inserting (NOT EXECUTING) in Codeigniter Framework

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to print query before inserting in database in **CODEIGNITER**.

***PHP CODE :***

```
    $data['prices'] = $prices;
    $data['countryID'] = '0';
    $data['userTypeID'] = $roleType;
    $data['districtDivisionID'] = '0';
    $data['userTypeValue'] = $userTypeValue;
    $data['receiverUserTypeID'] = $receiverUserType;
    $this->db->insert('db_DevicePrices', $data);
```

Comment: use `echo $this->db->last_query()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Echo query before execution and without execution in codeigniter Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010128/echo-query-before-execution-and-without-execution-in-codeigniter-active-record)

Comment: @ Devsi Odedra it is working with $this->db->get(); not for inserting. I have already check it.

Comment: @Prabhjot Singh Kainth  i have already check this. But no solution get.

Comment: @SandeepK. what is the output/error you are getting?

Comment: @Prabhjot Singh Kainth  There are no error display. and also data is not inserting, so far i will search for print query function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use insert_string, please take a look at following example.

```
$data = array( 
        'name'  = >  $_POST['name'] , 
        'groupname'= >  $_POST['groupname'], 
        'age'   = >  $_POST['age']
);
$this-> db->insert_string('tbl_user', $data);
```

Refer to [this link](http://www.bsourcecode.com/codeigniter/codeigniter-insert-query/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **$this->db->insert_string()** for print insert query before inserting data in database

Example:

```
$data = array('prices' => $prices, 'countryID' => 0, 'userTypeID' => $roleType,'districtDivisionID'=>0,'userTypeValue'=>$userTypeValue,'receiverUserTypeID'=>$receiverUserType);
$str = $this->db->insert_string('db_DevicePrices', $data);
```

Refer this [link](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html)

Hope this will help you.